# Twitter API - GET search/tweets for hashtag returns "Could not authenticate you"

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, postman

I'm using [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) to make GET requests from the Twitter API, but having some quirky issues when using search/tweets for a particular hashtag.  My goal is to return a list of recent tweets that have the same #hashtag.  I'm following along with Twitter's instructions on how to do this, which can be found [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) (look under the header 'Query Parameters').

**This returns the below JSON response**

`GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23somehashtag`

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Could not authenticate you",
            "code": 32
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using OAuth 1.0, also based on Twitter's docs.  I can make successful calls to the same endpoint by simply removing the `%23`:

`GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=somehashtag`

Answer (score 0):

Since you use OAuth 1.0 this suggests the the code that generates the signature does not correctly include the `%23` in the payload that is signed. Switching to OAuth 2.0 will make sending authorized requests easier and future proof.

Comment: that results in %23hashtag, which is what the @sean-connely already tried. I'm having this issue too.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to encode the #.  Don't need to go to OAuth2

var url="https....?q="+encodeURIComponent("#hashtag")

and it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue with POSTMAN, and it seems like a bug

I've found this in a different scenario

> GET parameters that have been URL encoded need to be decoded before adding to oAuth.
>   https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/pull/112

it seems there is no way to tell postman to not encode, but in my code it just works

Answer (score 0):

Responding to an old post , but using **Bearer Token** on Postman is working for me to resolve this authorization issue ( code 32) of using #hashtag in query

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23somehastag&result_type=recent